# Migrate Linux system by copying data to a new installation

Tags: ubuntu, raid, storage, migration, live-migration

I have a running development server, that hosts an Ubuntu Server on an OLAP secured SSD. The target board where I want to migrate this system can not unlock the SSD (because it had been locked by a different controller).

In addition to this, I would like to migrate the system to another unsecured RAID of HDDs. (The target board has a RAID controller, the source board has not.)

Goals: migrate data with the less time spent offline.

My idea: Would it be possible, to

1. Prepare the target RAID of HDDs and install (in terms of version) the same Ubuntu Server onto it.
2. Copy the contents of the original SSD over SSH to the target RAID of HDDs.
3. Benefit.

As far as I can see the problem:

- The SSD is risky to be unlocked, there is a chance of data loss, since the controller and the method is unreliable.
- The SSD can not be read by the target board.
- The RAID of HDDs can not be read by the source board.

Cheers

Comment: Do you use LVM on development server?

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy No LVM has been set up on the development server.

Comment: Is rsync an option?
You could rsync the whole filesystem once ahead for testing (many guides available telling how to backup with rsync) then once you get your "old" copy running on the new machine you just sync the relevant changes from the production system and just migrate...
At least for me it's hard to tell how you could do all this without testing things on your machines...

Comment: OK, I will try `rsync` and look for the guides as well. Thanks!